# Suppose $k|n$ and $p^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod{2n}$. Does $n$ divide $p^{k-1} + \cdots + p + 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am working on a finite field theory/number theory question, and my problem has been simplified down, via a chain of "if and only if"s, to the above question. The precise problem and its suppositions are as follows:

> Suppose $n\geq2$, $k>1$ such that $k|n$, and $p$ is an odd prime such
> that $p^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod{2n}$. Then $n|p^{k-1} + \cdots + p + 1$.

The supposition is a bit weird, and some of them may be unnecessary for the problem. I have checked a few numbers, and it seems to be true, but I am unsure of how to approach proving it. I have looked at using the *Euler Totient function*, but I wasn't able to get far. Is there some kind of sleek number theory/group theory argument or trick that I am forgetting?

Thank you so much for the help!

Edit: Thank you so much for your helpful counterexamples. They helped prove my original conjecture false. However, I now wonder what conditions on $n$, $k$, and $p$ *would* be necessary to satisfy $n|p^{k-1}+\cdots+p+1$. If you have any extra tips, I would love to hear them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an extension to the answer Dietrich provided. It's possible to come with many, many counterexamples. Because $p-1$ is always even, take $p,n$ such that $p-1=2n$, $n$-not prime and $k<n$. With this, we have
$$p-1=2n \Rightarrow \\
p\equiv 1 \pmod{2n} \Rightarrow \\
p\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
Then
$$1\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
$$p\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
$$p^2\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
$$...$$
$$p^{k-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
or
$$p^{k-1}+...+p^2+p+1 \equiv k \pmod{n} \tag{1}$$
Because $k<n$, then $k \not\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ always and from $(1)$
$$n \nmid p^{k-1}+...+p^2+p+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample. Let $n=6$ and $k=3$ and $p=13$. Then
$$
p^{k}=13^3=2197\equiv 1\bmod 12.
$$
but
$$
6=n\nmid p^2+p+1=183.
$$

Comment: Basically, it works for any $p-1=2n$ and $k<n$ ...

Comment: Yes, this was my idea. $p^k-1=(p-1)(p^{k-1}+\cdots +p+1)$. So if $2n\mid p-1$, then the second factor need not always have a divisor $n$.